# Which one performs faster? sql order by or java PriorityQueue or any other?

Tags: java, jdbc, queue, priority-queue

When U make a query JDBC which is faster, order by the query or use a PriorityQueue or any other to sort .

Comment: Your question is probably too broad right now. Please provide an example query in at least one of these syntax.

Comment: if I do a simple `code` select * from table_a `code` instead I use order by I use PriorityQueue with comparator or any other

Comment: The answer to "which is faster" type questions is "time it yourself and find out."

Answer (score 0):

If the result set is small it won't matter, and if it is large you will need the database to do the sorting for space reasons, so there is really no question to answer. Don't keep a dog and bark yourself. Use ORDER BY.